# How to draw a round platform that meets the requirements?

Tags: graphics

[image]

The specific appearance of the round platform is shown in the figure above.

In the right -angle trapezoid AA1B1B, A1B1 is parallel to AB, AA1 is vertical and AB, AB = AA1 = 2A1B1 = 6, right -angle trapezoid AA1B1B around the straight corner AA1 to get the round platform A1A in the picture above. On the BC, the size of the two-sided angle B1-AA1-C1 is α, and the size of α can be adjusted, and it is not sure

Some of my personal attempts, write this code. Why is a cylinder drawn?

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 6}}, {6, 3}], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

So far, answers and answers in answers and comments do not meet the requirements. My requirement is that the image form I draw is consistent with the pictures I give. Don't add curved color or the like, just be consistent with the picture given.

Comment: Please show what have you tried, share your Mathematica code in well-formatted `InputForm`. What is the part that you are finding challenging? Please [edit] your question to improve it and show minimum due diligence.

Comment: @rhermans I have Modified issues

Comment: As shown in the documentation for `Cylinder`, you must specify the same number of cylinders as there are radii specified. "Cylinder[{Subscript[spec, 1], Subscript[spec, 2], \[Ellipsis]}, {Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2], \[Ellipsis]}] represents a collection of cylinders with specifications Subscript[spec, i] and radii Subscript[r, i]." For example, `Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 6}}}, {6, 3}], Boxed -> False]`

Answer (score 2):

We're given that AB = 6. Let's call that the `lowerRadius`. We're given that AA1 =6. Let's call that the `frustumHeight`. We're given that A1B1 = 3. Let's call that the `upperRadius`. That's all we need to build a frustum.

```
lowerRadius = 6;
upperRadius = 3;
frustumHeight = 6;
coneHeight = frustumHeight*lowerRadius/(lowerRadius - upperRadius);
DiscretizeRegion[
  CSGRegion[
    "Intersection", 
    {Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, coneHeight}}, lowerRadius],
     Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, frustumHeight}}, lowerRadius]}]]
```

[image]

We used 6 for the height of the cylinder, 6 for the base radius of the cone and cylinder, and we had to calculate the height of the cone we needed, which turned out to be 12.

Alternatively, we can just use Mathematica's knowledge of solids.

```
frustumRegionFunction = EntityValue[Entity["Solid", "SolidConicalFrustum"], "Region"];
DiscretizeRegion[frustumRegionFunction[lowerRadius, upperRadius, frustumHeight]]
```

[image]

The region function takes as arguments the base radius, the top radius, and the height.

Comment: My requirement is that the image form I draw is consistent with the pictures I give. Don't add curved color or the like, just be consistent with the picture given.

Comment: So, dotted lines, labels, all of the same points, the same scale, etc?

Comment: Yes, draw on the picture I give. Very simple line segment and two rounds of round faces.

Comment: What fee are you offering?

Comment: Thank you for providing the code!
You don't want to help further, I don't force you! voluntarily